# WiringPi Library and PCA9685 throwing errows

Tags: pi-3, i2c, wiringpi

I am using this example code [PCA9685 in C](http://osoyoo.com/2017/07/12/raspberry-pi-starter-kit-lesson-12-raspberry-pi-drive-sg90-servo/) and whenever I run the code I get this as my output:

```
PCA9685 servo example
Connect a servo to any pin. It will rotate to random angles
pwmWrite: You have not called one of the wiringPiSetup
functions, so I'm aborting your program before it crashes anyway.
```

I ran the example code using:

```
sudo./servo
```

and still no luck. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I put this line of code and it works:

```
 wiringPiSetupGpio(); // Initalize Pi GPIO
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, before using any of the wiringPi functions, you have to initialize. One was already mentioned. There are other initialization functions, depending on what you want to do with wiringPi.
[wiringPi setup](http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/)